# What is the WIX SymbolPath element for?

Tags: wix, symbols, pdb-files

can anyone shed any light on the **WIX** `SymbolPath` element http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_symbolpath.htm? The documentation is pretty sparse. Is it for specifying where to find the symbols for a file? (In particular, a .NET assembly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's used to optimize binary-delta patches.

Comment: Can you go into more detail? Is "Symbol" in this case just any Directory, File, Media, Product, etc. on the disk?